# Using ArcSDE API in .NET(C#)

Tags: c#, .net, arcgis

Is possible to use ArcSDE API in .NET(C#) ?

http://edndoc.esri.com/arcsde/9.2/api/capi/dbconnects/dbconnects.htm

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is. By using PInvoke, you can call unmanaged code

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is, but it's mostly undocumented and painfull, as Henri said, by Using PInvoke, Marshal and Unmarshall, for unmanaged types, add 1 more char for \0 in unmanaged strings, set project to allow unsafe code.

If you have some C skills, you better use it instead, it is easier to debug.
In any way, it is really hard to do some clean and reusable code.

ESRI has much proprietary and under lisence stuff to protect that they will probably never publish a C# API.